# Start and Stop indicatorView and put it in centre tableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using a spinner in bottom of `tableView` to show the spinner when data is reloading.

```
var sneakers: [sneakerModel] = []
```

I stored all my data in sneakers and returning the count on `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.sneakers.count
}
```

And now I am using `willDisplay` method to show the spinner in bottom.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1

if indexPath.row == self.sneakers.count - 1 && !didPageEnd {
    pageNo += 1
    getSneakerSearch()
 }

    if (indexPath.row == self.sneakers.count) {
       self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
    } else {

    if indexPath.section ==  lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex {
     let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
     spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
     spinner.color = .red
     spinner.startAnimating()
     spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(5), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))

     self.tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
     self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
        }

    }

}
```

But it is not working. How can I stop spinner when no more data is loading. Please help?

Getting the data from api.

```
func getSneakerSearch() {

   let param: [String:Any] = [ "search_term" :  searchText ?? "","page": pageNo, "token": commonClass.sharedInstance.userToken ?? ""]

    if self.pageNo == 0{
        commonClass.sharedInstance.startLoading()
    }
    Alamofire.request(Constants.API.url("search"), method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        commonClass.sharedInstance.stopLoading()

        guard let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] else {return}
        printD(json)

        guard let status = json["status"] as? Int else {return}
        printD(status)


        if status == 1 {

            guard let data = json["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else { return}
            printD(data)
            if self.pageNo == 0 {
                self.sneakers.removeAll()
            }
            for item in data {
                guard let description =  item["description"] as? String else { return}
                printD(description)
                self.sneakers.append(sneakerModel(response: item))
            }
            self.didPageEnd = data.count < limitPerPage

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try **self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true** whenever the data has loaded successfully from the API.

Comment: Where in calling api method ?

Comment: Yes. In the API response methods inside.

Comment: Updated my question with calling api tell me where to call this method

Comment: **DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.reloadData()
            self.yourTableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
        }**

Comment: I tried that but it won't work

Comment: Try by placing getSneakerSearch() method inside if indexPath.section ==  lastSectionIndex && indexPath.row == lastRowIndex and remove it from if indexPath.row == self.sneakers.count - 1 && !didPageEnd

Comment: Can you add as an answer instead of comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create loadingview in viewdidload

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
    spinner.color = .red
    spinner.startAnimating()
    spinner.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(5), width: tableView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
    self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
}
```

and update `willDisplay cell`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let lastSectionIndex = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
    let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSectionIndex) - 1

    if indexPath.row == self.sneakers.count - 1 && !didPageEnd {
        pageNo += 1
        getSneakerSearch()
    }
}
```

Update getSnackerSearch func:

```
...
    if self.pageNo == 0{
        commonClass.sharedInstance.startLoading()
    }else{
        self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
    }
    Alamofire.request(Constants.API.url("search"), method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        if self.pageNo == 0{
            commonClass.sharedInstance.stopLoading()
        }else{
            self.tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
        }

    }
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer I will try that but one more I want it in centre How can I achieve this ?

Comment: var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(....

and add spinner to self.view

Answer (score 0):

For **center** of you spinner to tableview you can follow these steps to do it. You don't need to provide height and width for spinner.

```
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .whiteLarge
    spinner.color = .red
    spinner.startAnimating()

    let topBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
        (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)

    spinner.center=CGPointMake(self.tableView.center.x, self.tableView.center.y- topBarHeight);
```

Comment: getting error Use of unresolved identifier `statusBarHeight` and `navigationHeight`